# servlet not found error in cPanel godaddy.com

Tags: java, web-services, servlets, web, web-hosting

I'm having an already registered domain name on ***godaddy.com*** such as www.example.com(for example) and having a cPanel account. I've deployed my project's .war file and uploaded it into cPanel and then extracted it. When I access my domain(www.example.com), initial index.jsp file is getting loaded and all the javascript files work perfectly. But when it has to raise an AJAX request from javascript file, It says '404 error. Servlet not found!'. Well my servlet and class files are under **Public_html/WEB-INF/classes/com/Fb/FaceBookServlet.java** folder and here is my web.xml file

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>FaceBookServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.Fb.FaceBookServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>FaceBookServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/FaceBookServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

*Important thing is **"It works well in eclipse and doesn't when it comes to online"*** .... Please help me solve this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOMyd.png)

Here is the structure
Here is my **index.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Js/FaceBookSDK.js"></script>
<script 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Js/Fb.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loginBtn').click(function() {
        FacebookApp.signInPage();
    });
    $('#logoutBtn').click(function() {
        FacebookApp.signOutPage();
    });
    $('#postFeed').click(function() {
        FacebookApp.postFeedOnWall();
    });
    $('#postPhoto').click(function() {
        FacebookApp.findGameOfThronesCharacter();
    });
});
</script>

<input type="button" value="Sign in to Facebook" id="loginBtn"><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Sign out" id="logoutBtn"><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Post your message" id="postFeed"><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Post your photo" id="postPhoto"><br><br>
<img id="img"></img>

</body>
```

**FaceBookServlet.java :**

```
package com.Fb;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public final class FaceBookServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public FaceBookServlet() {
    super();

}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        String picture_source = request.getParameter("picture_source");
        String local_picture_directory = 
request.getParameter("local_picture_directory");
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.nextInt(5)+1;
        BufferedImage image1 = ImageIO.read(new URL(picture_source));
        BufferedImage image2 = ImageIO.read(new 
URL(local_picture_directory+randomNumber+".png"));
        image1 = resizeImage(image1,200,200);
        image2 = resizeImage(image2,200,200);
        int w = 2*image1.getWidth();
        int h = image1.getHeight();
        BufferedImage combined = new BufferedImage(w, h, 
BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = combined.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(image2, image1.getWidth(), 0, null);
        g.dispose();
        ImageIO.write(combined, "PNG", new File("Image.png"));
        obj.put("filename", "Image.png");
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().print(obj);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {

    }
}
public BufferedImage resizeImage(BufferedImage image,int width,int 
height) {
    BufferedImage newImage = new 
BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g = newImage.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    g.dispose();
    return newImage;
}

}
```

**Fb.js :**

```
var FacebookApp = {
    isConnected : null,
    signInDetails: null,
    IMAGEFILE_DIRECTORY: "http://www.sellu.online/Images/",
    signInPage: function() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if(response.status==='connected') {
                FacebookApp.isConnected = 1;                    
                FB.api('/me',
{fields:'name,id,birthday,locale,first_name,last_name,picture,gender'}, 
function(resp) {
                if(resp) {
                    FacebookApp.signInDetails = resp;
                }   
                });
                alert("Signed in Successfully!!")
            } else {
                FB.login(FacebookApp.getUserData, {scope: 
'email,public_profile,user_birthday,publish_actions', return_scopes: 
true});
            }
            });
    },
     getUserData: function(response) {
        if(response.authResponse) {
            FacebookApp.signInPage();
        } else {
            alert("Sorry!!! Can't get into facebook");
        }
    },
    signOutPage: function() {
        if(FacebookApp.isConnected === null) {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
                if(response.status === 'connected') {
                    FacebookApp.isConnected = 1;
                } else {
                    FacebookApp.isConnected = 0;
                }
                FacebookApp.signOutResult();
            });
        } else {
            FacebookApp.signOutResult();
        }
    },
    signOutResult: function() {
        if(FacebookApp.isConnected === 1) {
            FB.logout(function(response) {
                if(response) {
                    FacebookApp.isConnected = 0;
                    alert("Logged out successfully");
                } else {
                    alert("Can't logged out!!");
                }
            });
        } else if(FacebookApp.isConnected === 0) {
            alert("You've not logged in before!!");
        }
    },
    postFeedOnWall: function(content,picSrc,webLink) {
        FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: 
content,source:picSrc,link:webLink }, function(response) {
              if (!response || response.error) {
                  console.log(response.error);
                alert('Error occured in posting feed');
              } else {
                alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
              }
            });
    },
    postPhotoOnWall: function(picSrc,picCaption) {
        FB.api('/me/photos', 'post', { url: picSrc,caption: 
picCaption}, function(response) {
              if (!response || response.error) {
                  console.log(response.error);
                alert('Error occured in posting picture');
              } else {
                alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
              }
            });
    },
    findGameOfThronesCharacter: function() {
        var params={};
        params.picture_source = FacebookApp.getProfilePicture(500);
        params.local_picture_directory = null;
        if(FacebookApp.signInDetails && 
FacebookApp.signInDetails.gender) {
            if(FacebookApp.signInDetails.gender === 'male') {
                params.local_picture_directory = 
FacebookApp.IMAGEFILE_DIRECTORY + 'GOT/MEN/';
            } else {
                params.local_picture_directory = 
FacebookApp.IMAGEFILE_DIRECTORY + 'GOT/WOMEN/';
            }
        }
        $.post('FaceBookServlet',params,function(result) {
            if(result.filename) {
                $('#img').removeAttr('src');

$('#img').attr('src',FacebookApp.IMAGEFILE_DIRECTORY+result.filename);
                FacebookApp.postFeedOnWall("Find your game of thrones 
character!!",
FacebookApp.IMAGEFILE_DIRECTORY+result.filename,"www.sellu.online");
            }
        }); 
    },
    getProfilePicture: function(width) {
        var src = null;
        if(FacebookApp.signInDetails) {
            src = 
'https://graph.facebook.com/'+FacebookApp.signInDetails.id+"/picture?
type=large";
            if(width) {
                src += '&width='+width;
            }
        }
        return src;
    }

}
```

**FaceBookSDK.js :**

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        cookie     : true,  
        xfbml      : true,  
        version    : 'v2.8' 
      });
};
      (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Comment: you might want to use additional tags, to reach a bigger audience

Comment: Add your FaceBookServlet.java & index.jsp code here.

Comment: 'Public_html/WEB-INF/classes/com/Fb/FaceBookServlet.java folder '. You have a Java source file under a classes directory? Is this not compiled? I suspect a packaging issue rather than anything directly related to the source...

Comment: Both FaceBookServlet.java and FaceBookServlet.class files are under the same folder.... Then will it be ok if I delete the package and put the files under Public_html/WEB-INF/classes folder???